# I have a CSV file with header. Want to remove first 5 row of csv but not header? In Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I have a below CSV file with the header(A,B,C,D):

```
A,B,C,D
1,2,3,4
2,1,3,5
6,8,0,9
4,7,9,2
2,5,4,9
1,1,7,3
2,9,5,6
```

I want output after removing top 5 lines but not header:

```
A,B,C,D
1,1,7,3
2,9,5,6
```

Below is my Python code snippet, but am not able to add any header retaining code:

> with open(filename.csv , 'rb') as infile:
>               data_in = infile.readlines()
>
> with open ('temp.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
>               outfile.writelines(data_in[5:])

Please help me in this.In my case header is also deleting, but I want to retain header every time.

Comment: simple solution: use two `outfile.writelines()` commands, one for `data_in[0]` and then for `data_in[5:]`.

Comment: Thankyou @VBB , it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
with open ('temp.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.writelines(data_in[0])
    outfile.writelines(data_in[5:])
```

Answer (score 1):

> I advise using pandas as it will retain the header and you can perform
>   multiple operations on data with ease. A pandas dataframe can represent 2D data in form of columns and rows similar to a csv file.

Load file into pandas dataframe

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
```

Then select the required rows

```
df_temp = df.loc[5:]
```

Here is required output

```
   A  B  C  D
5  1  1  7  3
6  2  9  5  6
```

you can further write it to a csv file

```
df_temp.to_csv('output.csv',index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`islice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to avoid reading the whole file into memory:

```
from itertools import islice
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'rb') as f_input, open('output.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input)
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(next(csv_input))
    csv_output.writerows(islice(csv_input, 5, None))
```

Giving you an output of:

```
A,B,C,D
1,1,7,3
2,9,5,6
```

This first reads the first line and writes it to the output. It then uses `islice()` to skip over 5 lines and then pass the remaining lines to `writerows()`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise **against** even parsing the file or reading it whole in memory just to slice it. If you just want to do away with some lines in the middle all you need is to read the input file line by line and decide which lines to write to the output file and which ones to skip:

```
skip_lines = range(1, 6)  # the range is zero-indexed

with open("input.csv") as f_in, open("output.csv", "w") as f_out:
    current_line = 0  # keep a line counter
    for line in f_in:  # read the input file line by line
        if current_line not in skip_lines:
            f_out.write(line)  # not in our skip range, write the line
        current_line += 1  # increase the line counter
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise to use csv.DictReader and csv.DictWriter:

```
filename = os.path.join(datapath, "input.csv")
with open(filename, 'rb') as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile) 
    data_in = [row for row in reader]
    fieldnames = reader.fieldnames

filename = os.path.join(datapath, "temp.csv")
with open(filename, 'wb') as outfile: 
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(data_in[5:])
```