# How to copy CSV file with 50000 rows and a header to another CSV,with some conditions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, csv

I want to copy a huge csv file to another csv file but skip starting 100 lines first file and retainheader, at a same time I want to ignore unwanted commas which are in-between some names which are in quotes, like- "Hey, Roger"

Input data:

```
    Header------>
EPINASTINE HCL 0.05% EYE DROPS,51991083675,7.75853,03/23/2016,ML
EPINASTINE HCL 0.05% EYE DROPS,51991083675,7.75853,03/23/2016,ML
EPINASTINE HCL 0.05% EYE DROPS,51991083675,7.75853,03/23/2016,ML
HYDROMORPHONE 2 MG TABLET,68084042301,0.08511,03/23/2016,EA
"BICILLIN L-A 2,400,000 UNITS",60793070210,54.03213,01/01/2016,ML
EPINASTINE HCL 0.05% EYE DROPS,51991083675,7.75853,03/23/2016,ML
```

In fifth row "BICILLIN L-A 2,400,000 UNITS" is one element and contains comma in-between , which I want to either ignore or replace by space and also want to ignore top 3 rows. so output.csv will look like:

```
Header------>
    HYDROMORPHONE 2 MG TABLET,68084042301,0.08511,03/23/2016,EA
    "BICILLIN L-A 2 400 000 UNITS",60793070210,54.03213,01/01/2016,ML
    EPINASTINE HCL 0.05% EYE DROPS,51991083675,7.75853,03/23/2016,ML
```

please help me on this.
Below is my snippet:

```
       with open(filename , 'rb') as infile:
            data_in = infile.readlines()

        with open ('temp.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
            outfile.writelines(data_in[0])
            outfile.writelines(data_in[3:])
        os.remove(filename)    
        os.rename('temp.csv',filename)
```

I am not getting a way to replace unwanted commas in this.

Comment: I'm not a python guru, but I have used CSV files (sadly).  The indicator there are included commas are those double quotes around a field.  In the case where you want to remove those "extra" commas,  focus on a regex that matches fields that are enclosed in quotes, then strip the commas from those, then use that string (sans quotes is my suggestion).  As far is keeping header and dropping certain lines, i'd use an iterator to skip a group of lines, do your record processing then append to the target file.  Good luck.

Comment: you have written: 1) *skip starting 100 lines first file and retainheader* ; 2) *want to ignore top 3 rows*. So, what are your actual exact conditions?

Comment: your have to loop row by row over your `data_in` and code skips/corrections the way you want to have it with if statements etc. Then it's a matter of taste if you put your corrected rows in a list and write that at the end, or if you write row by row as they are processed.

Comment: You can combine [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47692066/7553525) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47697066/7553525) to your earlier questions and reach the desired solution, or are you going to repeat your questions step by step until the SO community does all the work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to access the file line by line since you have an interesting requirement of keeping the first row (the header) but then a gap and also do some regex work on the various lines. Your code should look something like this:

```
import os
filename = "name_of_file.csv"
with open(filename , 'rb') as infile:
  with open ('temp.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    start_row = 3;
    row_count = 0;
    for line in infile.readlines():
      if row_count >= start_row:
        # find all matches for commas inside double quotes
        regex = b"\".*?,.*?\""
        matches = re.findall(regex, line)
        for match in matches:
          # for each match found, remove unwanted commas and replace them
          new_cell = match.replace(b',', b' ')
          line = re.sub(match, new_cell, line)
        # write line to file
        outfile.write(line)
      elif row_count == 0:
        # header row, copy it
        outfile.write(line)
      row_count += 1
os.remove(filename)    
os.rename('temp.csv',filename)
```